# Why can't I execute some trivial PHP code in my Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel

I am working toward debugging a Laravel 9 app that I am building to get a better understanding of how the edit() and update() methods of my controller work but I can't find anything that describes how to invoke XDebug in VS Code for a Laravel project so I'm trying to work through a video that shows how to do ordinary PHP code in VS Code but that's not working either.

In fact, I can't even get my trivial webpage with trivial PHP to *display* properly in my web browser. I don't know if I'm simply having a Stupid Day or if there is some step I need to take to make my browser interpret PHP properly instead of treating it all like a big comment.

Here's the webpage with its PHP code that I am trying to display in my browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <h1>My Glorious Title</h1>
        <?php
            echo "Hello world!";
        ?>
        <?php 
            $text = "Debugging fun with Laravel and PHP";
            echo $text;
            for ($ix=0; $ix<5; $ix++) {
                print( $ix);
            }
            echo "  ";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is what the browser (Firefox) sees when I do CTRL-SHIFT-i:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <h1>My Title</h1>
        <!--?php echo "Hello world!"; ?-->
        <!--?php 
            $text = "Debugging fun with Laravel and PHP";
            echo $text;
            for ($ix=0; $ix<5; $ix++) {
                print( $ix);
            }
            echo "  ";
        ?-->
    </body>
</html>
```

The webpage itself displays only the h1 tag since all the PHP has been commented out.

The PHP code is clearly not being recognized as such but I don't understand why since my Laravel project is full of PHP and works fine.

My file, test01.php, is sitting in the root directory for my project. I'm running on Windows 10 home using an Administrator ID so I can't see this being a security issue. How do I make my browser recognize this as actual PHP code that it should execute?

UPDATE:

I amended my source code so that it was exactly this:

```
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <h1>My Title</h1>
        @php "Hello world!"; @endphp

        <?php 
            $text = "Debugging fun with Laravel and PHP";
            echo $text;
            for ($ix=0; $ix<5; $ix++) {
                print( $ix);
            }
            echo "  ";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is what I got on my page:

```
My Title
@php "Hello world!"; @endphp
```

When I tried using "double-moustache" syntax around the first PHP block like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <h1>My Title</h1>
        {{"Hello world!";}} 

        <?php 
            $text = "Debugging fun with Laravel and PHP";
            echo $text;
            for ($ix=0; $ix<5; $ix++) {
                print( $ix);
            }
            echo "  ";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I got this on my webpage:

```
My Title
{{"Hello world!";}}
```

The things I put around my PHP code to delineate it as PHP code are simply not being recognized.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to tell your server to properly process PHP files using PHP. How are you running the server and what configuration are you using?

Comment: @Mike - I'm not using the server at all really. I'm trying to take advantage of the fact that I've got some HTML with some PHP code in it and the fact that the browser should be executing the PHP as a result of simply clicking on the file from File Explorer. That's worked for me many times in the past with other projects but somehow Laravel or VS Code is keeping it from working. Or at least that's how it seems to me.

Comment: @Henry that's not how PHP works. Browsers don't execute PHP, the PHP is processed on your server and the server returns HTML/JS/CSS to your browser.

Comment: Remember that PHP code  _is not HTML_, it needs to be run by PHP to _produce_ HTML, so you need a server that has been set up to run the PHP processor for any PHP code in your project. You don't get a choice here, PHP is a server side scripting language: not only won't it do anything in the browser, it conceptually _can't_ do anything in the browser. Thankfully, Laravel already comes with everything you need, so it might be time to (re)read up on how to run your Laravel project so you can properly see and use it =)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to use PHP in a blade template. This is possible, but you'll need to wrap your PHP in `@php` and `@endphp`:

```php
@php
    $i = 0;
    $i++;
    echo $i;
@endphp
```

[Check the docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#raw-php)

Comment: I tried changing doing that for the first of the two PHP blocks but then it simply displayed the whole first block verbatim, including the tags.

Comment: You shouldn't be putting tags inside `@php` and `@endphp`

Comment: Sorry, I tried to type what I actually wrote but the editor objected to me typing two strings beginning with at signs; apparently, it thought I was trying to direct my comment to two different users. Yet somehow you got away with it in your reply. I'll update my post with what I actually wrote.

Comment: @Henry Ok, I think I've worked it out. You're not even rendering this as a blade template, it's got nothing to do with Laravel. You're just opening a .php file in your browser.

Comment: @Henry PHP stands for PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor. The preprocessor bit needs to happen on your server (which you're circumventing by just opening the file directly).

Comment: @Henry Your Laravel project is working fine, but this file *is not your Laravel project*

Comment: Stick it inside your Laravel project, open it through whatever local server you have hosting your Laravel project, and it'll work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I was indeed having a "Stupid Day" yesterday and I have now got my PHP code to execute properly by following some of the advice in various answers.

Here's what I did:

- I deleted the first php block, the one where I tried using `@php` and then `@endphp` and then `{{ }}`; the second php block was unchanged and still used `<?php` and `?>`.
- I renamed the file so that it is test01.blade.php instead of
  test01.php.
- I moved the file from the root directory of my project to
  the views folder.
- I created this route:

  Route::get('/test01', function () {
  return view('test01');
  });
- I executed `npm run dev` in a terminal window.
- I executed `php artisan serve` in another terminal window.
- I went to `localhost:8000/test01` and my file is now executing properly.

Thanks to all responders for helping me get back on track. Now I just have to figure out why I can't get Debug to run yet on my little play file but I'll create a fresh question if I can't figure it out myself.